# How to change Blackberry initial message download limit

Tags: blackberry, bes

BES 4.1.6
Blackberry 8300 (curve)

Hi guys,

I've noticed that handhelds will typically only retrieve the first few KB and then prompt the user to manually retrieve more (or auto-retrieve if they scroll down).  The problem is that I have a BB app that needs to see the entire message all at once on the first initial time it's opened.

Is there a setting on BES that will allow me to change how much data a handheld initially retrieves per message?

Thanks,

M

---

Perhaps I should clarify a bit more: Is there a way to increase the amount of data a BES device will receive beyond the default 2 KB threshold "chunk"?

Answer (score 1):

You can amend the packet size sent to the device in the MDS settings on the BES.

You want to goto general and Maximum KB/Connection.  I think the max is 1024, we moved this to 512 to handle more data.

not my knowledge i just googled your questions and got this from the blackberry forums hopefully it works

[Blackberry Support Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Enterprise-Solution/File-Size-Download-Limit-on-BlackBerry-Enterprise-Server/m-p/128445;jsessionid=0160E3E3F174F059EA1D023DABE3DB14)

Answer (score 1):

On the device look under Options -> Messages for 'Auto More'.

However there used to be a 'hard' limit of around 40Kb on messages sent to a device. If the messages are over that amount, I'm not sure there's a fix.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  The problem with Auto More is that the user still has to scroll down to the bottom of the screen before it loads the rest of the message.  My blackberry app requires the entire message to be downloaded immediately.  I was hoping there was a threshold somewhere on bes or the device to set this.